# Unbounded adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators, schauder-basis

I am learning about adjoints of unbounded operators on infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces.  I understand that the domain of such an adjoint (to operator $A$, from Hilbert space $H$ onto itself) is defined as

$$D_A* = \{v \in H |\,\exists w: w\cdot u = v \cdot Au, \forall u \in D_A\}$$

Question: Why is $D_A^*$ not simply all of $H$, in the case where $H$ is separable?

Consider the standard construction for the existence of $w$, given any $v \in H$:

Define $w = (v\cdot A e_1)e_1 + (v\cdot Ae_2)e_2 \dots$

where $e_1, e_2 \dots$ is an orthonormalized Schauder basis of separable Hilbert space $H$.

A simple check will confirm that, given any vector $u \in D_A$,
$$ w\cdot u = (v\cdot Ae_1)(e_1\cdot u) + (v\cdot Ae_2)(e_2\cdot u) … = v\cdot Au$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your steps go through **informally**, this means that in finite dimensions or if you don't have to bother about anything being unbounded, this is actually the case. In infinite dimensions, a problem arises. We know that $D_A$ cannot be the whole space (by the theorem of Hellinger-Toeplitz) and it can only be dense in $H$.

Assuming that $D_A$ is dense in $H$, it may be possible to find a Schauder basis such that $Ae_j$ is well-defined for all $j$. But now, in your last calculation you actually pull $A$ inside a limit. In your last step, consider

$$A u = A \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=0}^n (e_j \cdot u) e_j \neq  \lim_{n \to \infty} A \sum_{j=0}^n (e_j \cdot u) e_j = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (e_j \cdot u) A e_j, $$

in general because being unbounded for a linear operator is the same as failing to be continuous. It is sometimes useful to write out the limit like this so you see what can go wrong with unbounded/not continuous operators.

*Edited: Answer given was wrong, now it should be correct.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  

It was my understanding that $D_a$ is dense in $H$, and therefore, a Schauder basis spanning $D_a$ also spans $H$.  

Could we not choose $e_j$ to be such a basis of $D_a$??

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are totally right, I will edit my answer acordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer!  It was my understanding that an unbounded operator is discontinuous precisely because the $Av$ fails to exist for certain elements $v$ in $H$, and therefore $D_A$ is an appropriately restricted to a subset of H.  But $A$ is continuous within $D_A$.  Is this wrong?  If so, could you give me a counterexample?  

On the other hand, if it is true - and the definition of $D_A*$ checks all $u$ inside $D_A$ only - would $A$ not then be continuous at all the required points for the inequality in your answer to become equality?